# OLEDB C# Update and Insert data

Tags: c#, oledb

I have an issue when using `oledb` to insert or update data into excel file.
With normal data (which smaller 250 characters) my code is ok. But with larger data it is not ok.

```
OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:A1] 
SET F1= '" + **data_review** + "'", objConn);                                
objCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I use connection string below:

> String sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
>   Source=" + FileNameDonVi + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'";

When i excute update query, An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data

Comment: "not ok" - well, that's a clear description. What happens? Errors? Truncation? It orders anchovy pizza to be delivered to your house non-stop?

Comment: Share the error...

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: *[edit]* your question to add more details. Especially if it's code. Code is unreadable in the comments. But pay attention to the tools that others have already been using in editing your question - notably the code sample tool (`{}` in the toolbar) so that we get code samples with syntax highlighting.

Comment: @JohnB no it's not. There's no such limit. OLEDB is how most Windows applications connect to most data sources like SQL Server. Including SQL Server's own SSIS subsystem. Perhaps you confuse OLEDB for the *Jet Provider* or *Excel only*?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - ah yes my mistake - i will remove comment-   thank you.

Comment: @DuyNguyenTrong 255 is [the maximum column width in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). You can add more only if wrapping is enabled in the cell/column. What are you trying to do in the first place? Perhaps you should use a library like EPPlus instead to generate an Excel file with the formatting you want?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: But "Total number of characters that a cell can contain" is 32,767 characters, and I try to update 800 characters into a cell. I don't think that is the reason. I use Oledb because I have to update data into existed file.

Comment: @DuyNguyenTrong and `Column width: 255 characters`. As the duplicate explains, you can store 32K characters only if text wrapping is enabled for that cell. You can open the Excel file and change the style of the affected cell. Or you can use EPPlus to modify the data and styles in an existing file. The OLEDB provider can't modify styles

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I like EPPlus, but It doesn't support for .xls file :( I tried to change style of all cell in file, set wrap text, but not ok.

Comment: @DuyNguyenTrong that's because `xls` was abandoned 12 yeas ago. The Excel format is `xlsx`, not `xls`. *All* Excel versions since 2006 use `xlsx` by default.  You actually have to **pay** services like Google Sheets to handle `xls` files, for several years now. The reason is quite important -`xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. You don't even need Excel or any other provider to create or read them. The only reason you may want `xls` is that your client uses unsupported Excel versions like 2003 or earlier?

Comment: [File formats that are supported in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Yes, I and u know that, but my customers don't care, they still use office 2003. And I can't make them to update their office

Comment: @DuyNguyenTrong the easiset option is to open the Excel file and change the field's format then. If you can't, you'll have to change the format through code. One option would be to find and use a library that handles the `xls` format, like [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/). Another is to use Excel Interop to start Excel, load the sheet and modify the cell

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: thanks u, I will try other way. Maybe convert xls to xlsx and using EPPlus to process, or using Interop :)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: finally, I convert to xlsx and using EPPlus, It's ok :D